How to perform Draggable + DragTarget behavior using an onTap for Accessibility
We are building a memory game that requires us to perform the selection of a word in the word bank.
But instead of having to drag and drop the word directly, for accessibility purposes we want to use 'onTap' event of Gesture detector or Inkwell to execute the drag-n-drop action.
Using the Draggable and DragTarget functionality, we can perform the Drag-n-drop function. I'd like some recommendations on the best approach to do this with an 'onTap' event for the user.
